# firebase storage rule doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-storage

I'm using the default storage rule:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

or

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

But without login, download url still accessible. How to prevent it? https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sunshine-b9c43.appspot.com/o/user_icon%2FcwL09fN6x5fnaYBTbEXAHJ3rgxV2_1473299432313.jpg?alt=media&token=042803b7-a4f0-4728-9041-81e6d4b3eb1d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload your data to Firebase Storage, you will be provided with two 'links' to get to that data:

1. **The private link.** This link is only going to be accessible
   internally by authenticated users/devices.
2. **The public link.** This link will technically be readable by anyone
   with the link, however, the link is supposed to be highly
   un-guessable. The token at the end would be extremely hard to guess.
   If you remove this token and navigate to the link, you will see that
   the Firebase Server blocks your access.

If you are uncomfortable having that link still 'out there' for the world to see, you can revoke the link.

See in the picture below. I took a screenshot to show you the private 'gc//' link as well as the public 'http' link. See that little 'revoke' option? You can use that if you have specifically sensitive data that you do not want users to view.

[image]

**Update:**
It seems that at the time of writing this there is no API call or build in Firebase flag/function for getting rid of that public link; the only way is to manually revoke them, one at a time, through the FB Console. (ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aw86jf8b7PY) Mike Mcdonald also makes note of the fact that once the user has already seen the image, there is always the possibility that they downloaded or saved it anyways, so revoking the URL may or may not have any real security impact anyways.

Another option that comes to mind, however, is pulling the images to your server and hosting them from there using a temporary (one-time?) link to serve the image, keeping that public URL for your eyes only. This adds more work on the server end, but if you absolutely need the security, it might be an option you'll want to explore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. The getDownloadURL() function will give me the public URL and very easy to be used by <img>, but it's public URL, everyone can get it from <img> tag and bypass the login protection. Now, my question is how to use the the private URL for my web app? Any example?

Comment: I edited this comment after I re-read it because I didn't see the last part about the web app. Are these images going to be displayed only to users who have already been authenticated by your webapp (separate from Firebase Auth)? Also, what type of stack/framework are you using for your webapp if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I'm using Firebase Auth and Angular 2 for the web app, and I only want the images shared between authenticated users. Mobile client is using Ionic 2 which should be OK, because not easy to get the image URL from app. :) 
Also want to know if there is any API can revoke the download URL instead of revoke it manually?

Comment: Sorry for the delay Frank, I got held up this week. Take a look at this short forum post regarding what you are trying to do. It should shed a little light on the subject. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aw86jf8b7PY. It looks like Firebase doesn't have a good way of doing this quite yet, at least not for web.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank for your reply. I post my suggestion (using current user session instead of generated permanent token for download URL) in the google forum. Hope this kind of function will be available soon.

Comment: No problem. And I think that's a great suggestion. I hope they implement that too.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the token from firebase console, everyone can access this link:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fb-functions-xxx.appspot.com/o/assets%2Fhello.html?alt=media&token=xxxxxx-95d5-41cd-b827-329bbe6269fb

If the token was removed from the link, firebase storage rule will be applied.
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fb-functions-xxx.appspot.com/o/assets%2Fhello.html?alt=media